# Is pointers in c++ performing low-level memory manipulation?

Tags: c++11

So i was reading something about c++ in wiki and i came across this "low-level memory manipulation", it said c++ facilitates low-level memory manipulation. so first thing that came in my head was pointers

so can someone give me a brief and correct description what low-level memory manipulation actually means and examples of c++ features that does that.Don't comment if you are not sure.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B

Comment: You should have cited precisely your wiki and provide a link to it. We are missing a lot of context and can only guess. And since your question does not show any code, it is probably off-topic here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the text you are referring to is saying that raw pointer manipulation is low-level in genuine C++ and that idiomatic C++11 programs should use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (like [std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)) and standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (both internally would use raw 
pointers, but this is hidden to the programmer).

Low-level memory manipulation would mean *explicitly* use in your code raw pointers like `YourType* ptr;` and raw memory allocation like `ptr = new YourType(something);` and later explicit deletion with `delete ptr;`

You should read [Programming - Principles and practices using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Answer (score 0):

C++ evolved from C which is, by far, the dominant language for coding operating systems. The fundamental variable types closely adhere to those of the compiler's target machine and C is used as a kind of high level assembly language. A subset of C++ is increasingly used for the same purpose as it provides close to the metal programming. When C++ programmers look at the assy code they find a close correlation to their program source.